# How to exit out of a 'yes' loop

Tags: terminal, tty, signals, exit, yes

Using the command `yes` you can make a loop in the Linux terminal. 
How do you exit out of said loop? 
(I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but it didn't work).

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: ^ Yep can't reproduce.

Comment: Where and how did you start it? `^C` should have killed that `yes` command if you had started it by entering it at the prompt of an interactive shell in a terminal (with sane tty settings)

Comment: It happened to me, invoking alpine Linux with: `docker run -i --rm alpine /bin/ash` then entering `yes`. The only way to stop it was to kill the process from another terminal session, getting the id with `ps aux | grep docker`. For the "Ctrl + C" to work, I had to invoke Linux with adding the t option: `docker run -ti --rm alpine /bin/ash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stty -a` should give you a list of key shortcuts for your terminal. In particular, you should see a line that looks something like this:

`intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D;` ...

Presumably, you will not have ^C listed next to `intr =`. Try whatever combo is there instead; if that doesn't work, you can try your `quit` or `kill` combos as well -- here, `Ctrl + \` and `Ctrl + U`, respectively.